# Error when connecting qt and matlab

Tags: c++, matlab, qt

After putting following in .pro file of qt project (follow some tutorials)

```
INCLUDEPATH +=/Applications/Matlab/MATLAB_R2016a.app/extern/include
LIBS += -L/Applications/Matlab/MATLAB_R2016a.app/bin/maci64
```

I try to create engine pointer but my compiler show

> :-1: error: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
>   :-1: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Can any one help me how to solve this problem or how to connect qt with matlab?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have defined the *directory* in which to find the necessary shared libraries but you haven't specified the [*actual* libraries](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/compiling-engine-applications-in-an-ide.html#bssa6mq-2) using the `-l` flag

```
LIBS += -L/Applications/Matlab/MATLAB_R2016a.app/bin/maci64 -lmx -leng
```